# ¿Como pedir permisos al firewall de windows?

Tags: c, socket

Estoy haciendo un programa con sockets que le quiero pasar a unos amigos y que es un servidor. Para que funcione hay que darle permisos para el firewall de windows

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando aparece esta pestaña y le das a permitir acceso no funciona. Hay que seleccionar las casilla de redes publicas (Sinceramente no entiendo porque). ¿Hay alguna manera de que automáticamente salga seleccionada la casilla de abajo o que el programa pida permisos para lo que necesita?

Comment: La cosa depende es de cómo Windows identifique la red a la que se conecta, como pública o privada; nada tiene que ver con tu programa. Así pues, marquen las dos casillas y ya está.

Answer (score 0):

Probaste agregando el ejecutable socket.exe como una app permitida para comunicarse a través del firewall ?, dejo una captura de pantalla desde donde se realiza[image: excepcion a la aplicacion]

Comment: si que se añade ahora me funciona pero solo con ordenadores que están conctado al mismo rooter que yo